# Plausibility of an Implausible First Contact

Tags: science-based, xenobiology, meteor, firstcontact

*A long time ago near a planetary system far, far away, a great battle ensued between the Evil Commonwealth of the Fraternal Order of Mind Your Own Darn Business and the rebellious Expressors of the Eternal Finger. Missiles were launched in the deepest recesses of space. Energy was exchanged. Debris littered the area. And, of course, there were bodies....*

---

Humanity has been conditioned for decades to believe First Contact would be...

1. The gruesome revelation of decaying bodies in tanks of fluid due to a government conspiracy starting in (of all places) Roswell, NM back in the 40s.
2. A pleasant encounter when handsome aliens who look a bit like us but for some cosmetic surgery around the ears demonstrate what would be interpreted by any other sapient species as a vulgar hand gesture. Humans, of course, accept it as an alien handshake.
3. The discovery that open gun ports are considered a gesture of respect by a species that obviously doesn't think like us *at all....*
4. That adrenaline-rush moment when a brand new life form bursts joyfully from your best friend's chest. Not that you noticed. You're still running.

In reality, First Contact was much, much, much different. Assume for the sake of argument...

- An alien body has been slowly mogating through the Sagittarius Arm of the Galaxy. Not too fast (the battle having been <s>thousands</s> <s>millions</s> maybe billions of years ago), such that when it approaches Earth at *exactly* the right angle, it's caught in Earth's gravitational well but does NOT enter the atmosphere at a significant starting speed. Let's say 10 m/s.
- The body is obviously frozen rock solid. 70 Kg of mass.
- The body would be wearing a uniform and has a few tools/instruments useful to whatever job the poor schlemiel was doing before a hole was ripped in the hull right in front of him. The uniform would be fire-resistant such that it could withstand an open flame for 120 seconds.
- The body enters the atmosphere and has the good fortune of hitting the ground right in front of Grauman's Chinese Theater in California.
- It's December 31, 2020 (because this year absolutely *can't* end without some excitement).

**Question:** Can I expect to find enough of the alien to know that it is an alien (body, clothes, or equipment)?

*I included the meteor tag because... technically... what we have here is a meteor. Kinda. In the same way that D.B. Cooper was a parachutist.*

Comment: Small suggestion.
Instead of the whole he died and drifted into space. 
Make it so that this is a sort of deep space very resilient space pod cryogenic capsule.
Why?
You want to preserve enough of it after billions of years.
So. It only makes sense that he is put into something that is expected to survive those times. Since they are insanely advanced you can easily expect this pod to survive that long.
Also this adds another HUGE elements. 
The possibility of waking it up!
Imagine an alien corpse without a head. Bumper. But a frozen one? Maybe we can revive it!
See Javik, Mass Effect

Comment: An object coming from outer space will enter Earth's atmosphere with a speed of 11,186 m/s (40,270 km/h, 25,022 mph) *or more*. Cannot be less than that, unless it has engines to slow it down.

Comment: AlexP is referring to the fact that an object entering from a very low relative speed at a very large distance away is the time reversed situation of an object just barely escaping from Earth's surface. Both situations involve a minimum of 11.19 km/s at the encounter with/departure from Earth. Worse, solar escape velocity at the distance of Earth is 42 km/s, so you'll have 12-72 km/s of velocity "at infinity" and an even higher encounter velocity. An interstellar object is not going to have a gentle atmospheric entry.

Comment: @Seallussus also Kzanol, World of Ptavvs.

Comment: @Seallussus That's a great idea, but I'm looking to understand a specific effect.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff (And Alex), I did not know that, but it's a great fact and the core of an answer. So, if the minimum is 11 km/s, what's left at the bottom end of the proverbial rope?

Comment: So first contact is charred splattering of organic matter. There will be no recognizable clothing or tools.

Comment: That sounds like the least helpful first contact ever.

Comment: @Christopher James Huff Could the Earth-Moon system provide sufficient gravity to capture the incoming body in orbit? No smashing in front of Grauman's Chinese Theater in California but a frozen alien body periodically zipping in front of the window of the ISS is an equally fitting closure for 2020

Comment: @DuncanDrake not directly. A more complicated chain of events involving capture into the solar system, shifts to nearly-match Earth's orbit, and eventual capture into high Earth orbit is physically possible, just extraordinarily improbable.

Comment: @Christopher James Huff which is the reason why the improbability drive was invented I wager.

Comment: I think _schlemiel_ could be replaced with _schlemazel_.  There is no evidence that the creature was clumsy, just unlucky.

Comment: @kutschkem That's an incredibly good point, but who ever said first contact should be helpful? (In fact, that's a darn good premise for an entire book!)

Comment: @JBH Least helpful in that the only information it gives is that there are other civilizations out there, but we assume that already. Would it really change so much for us? We still would have no way to contact the others, we couldn't get much useful information from whatever remains after burning up in the atmosphere. A few scientific papers, a few alient cults, excitement for a while but after some time everything just goes back to normal!? Is my guess as to what would happen.

Comment: No possible capture events can slow the body to below orbital velocity.  (And I don't think it's possible to slow it to much below the velocity needed to reach the moon, but I am not as certain of that.)  A body that hits atmosphere at those speeds will be vaporized.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff Nonconservative forces, like friction or atmospheric drag, break time symmetry. Your statement about situations being time reversed in respect to each other would be correct if Earth had no atmosphere.

Comment: @Miech since essentially all of the trajectory of interest is well outside the atmosphere and not exposed to any significant drag forces, that's not really relevant. The difference in escape velocity at ground level and at 100 km is less than 90 m/s, the difference in encounter velocity for an object with a high initial velocity will be even lower.

Comment: @Miech  I'm thinking it could land like a space shuttle, but with slightly more maneuverability.  Perhaps it has short, stubby wings? :)

Answer (score 29):

All right, so first off, as @AlexP and @Christopher James Huff pointed out in the comments, no interstellar object could possibly enter the Earth's atmosphere at such a low speed. Any object from outside Earth's SOI would be going at a minimum of 11,186 m/s (because if it's going at a relative speed of 0 m/s when it enters, it will get to that speed by the time it reaches Earth) and any object entering Sol's SOI will be at 42,100 m/s by the time it reaches Earth's orbital height.

You said it's reaching Earth at just the right angle, so I'm going to assume that's just the right angle so the relative velocities help it not be so much. Just the right angle to encounter Earth's SOI would take away 29,780 m/s (Earth's orbital speed) and just the right angle to hit Earth itself would take away about 460 m/s (Earth's rotational speed at the surface, I'm assuming the 70km to the top of the atmosphere is more or less negligible compared to the 6,300 km of diameter). If I'm doing my calculations right (it's perfectly possible I'm not) that puts you at an **absolute minimum of about 23 km/s** when you reach Earth. Here are some comparisons of reentry speeds to give you some scale: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/9139/what-are-reentry-speeds-of-space-vehicles

Given that energy equals one half em vee squared, your 70 kg alien will deliver 18,515,000,000 Joules of energy to the Earth's atmosphere ([equivalent to about 43 tons of TNT](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/usefultables.php#boom)) which I can't imagine is good for it. You said it has flame-resistant clothing, but **I don't think it'll be enough.** Even space shuttles don't reenter at half this speed. Better tell the diners at Grauman's Chinese Theater to look up and make a wish before he fizzles out.

*Note: @ChristopherJamesHuff says "The minimum is closer to sqrt((11 km/s)^2 + ((42-30) km/s)^2) = 16 km/s...it's the amount of energy you gain falling into the gravity well that is fixed, not the velocity. The stop at the end is still going to hurt." As I said, my math in these cases is not perfect, so I'll leave both stats and let you decide. Either way, it's a lot of delta-v to be accounted for.*

Now, your figure of 10 m/s is a lot smaller than 23 km/s [citation needed]. Really, 10 m/s will have almost the exact same effect as just dropping it. Even if you were at that speed, you'd need parachutes when you get to the bottom, because if you start with no speed, the Earth is gonna pull you toward it at 10 m/s^2 until you *are* going fast enough to be slowed down by the atmosphere. Skydivers have about a 50 m/s terminal velocity, but your alien won't be paying too much attention to aerodynamics so it'll probably be a bit faster than that.

So, rather than just putting a damper on your idea, here are some ideas of how you can fix the problem:

- **Use an escape pod.** The alien was able to clamber into an escape pod. Unluckily, there was not enough food or water, so he died before reaching safety. Still, when the pod's computer recognizes an inhabitable planet, it uses boosters to slow down the pod before reentry.
- **Message in a bottle.** An SOS message from an alien could survive with some protective shielding. Don't know if that fits your story, but it might. There could be some nice "proof" that it's actually alien in the pod (proof in quotes because it'll never actually convince everyone, case in point flat earth theory)
- **The whole ship.** The whole ship went adrift! It could do the same as the escape pod (ie slow down) or it might just have really good heat shields and be able to take the blow. It might have parachutes. Now, this depends on what kind of battle this ship was meant for. If it was never supposed to reenter, it probably doesn't have all that great shielding. But hey, your alien's got a better chance in a ship than on his own, right? (Do note that you'd have to recalculate the energy released on the atmosphere given the ship/pod's weight)
- **Who knows?** This is your story, you know what fits it best. You can just take this answer as "only if you slow down" and work out your own solution. I would say, you definitely don't have to slow it down all the way to 10 m/s, that might actually make it *less* likely to survive because the reentry slowdown would start later and might not have time to finish slowing it down. I'd say 1,000-1,500 m/s would be a good range to aim for. If you have stats on the kind of idea you're going for, I'd be happy to help you calculate them.

Hope this helps. :) Just remember, don't let a minor setback such as it not being able to survive your original idea stop you. Just reconsider and re-plan. You'll probably end up with something even better! (It's not like it's rocket science or anything XD)

Comment: I suggest giving the escape pod some lifting body characteristics -- any sentients capable of making an orbit-to-ground escape pod ought to include enough redundancy for such minor matters as degradation or failure of the reentry boosters.  The pod would naturally aerobrake to reduce enough speed to have a chance of maintaining its atmosphere after it completes lithobraking.

Comment: And by "have a chance" I mean "the pod's contents are just sufficiently intact or identifiable for story purposes."

Comment: I suspect "any object entering Sol's SOI will be at 42,100 km/s" is a typo?

Comment: To get as close as possible to just the body landing, the escape pod could be an inflatable design that just barely runs out of ablator. It's structural integrity could fail after most/all of the heat, popping and depositing the corpse in front of the theater in however good/bad condition desired.

Comment: The escape pod need not use boosters;  one could imagine a [MOOSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOOSE)-like system being used as an emergency escape system near a planet, and some accident slingshotting the whole thing to Earth after untold eons of travel.

Comment: Maybe a space suit, rather than a whole pod, where the suit was designed to take a punch during combat (it was a war, after all) or for things like orbital halo jumps. This gives **plausibility** to a body surviving, because we can add in alien technology, even if the raw physics don't work well. And because it's just a suit, rather than a full pod, we can do it without also leaving any meaningful remnants of the suit technology behind that might push the story in ways the author doesn't want.

Comment: First, with sufficient luck that interstellar velocity can be pretty much shed by gravity assists.  A bit of the remaining velocity can be shed with an assist from the moon, but that still leaves you at orbital velocities.  And I think you are wrong on the TNT--Google is telling me 6kg of TNT per kg of object.  Did you perhaps lose a zero?

Comment: The minimum is closer to sqrt((11 km/s)^2 + ((42-30) km/s)^2) = 16 km/s...it's the amount of energy you gain falling into the gravity well that is fixed, not the velocity. The stop at the end is still going to hurt.

Comment: @LorenPechtel that's a lot of luck. There's probably some bits of interstellar gravel circling Earth after such a series of interactions, but there's a lot more bits of gravel in the universe than there are adrift alien astronauts...or so I assume. I think the only believable way for this to happen is some ridiculously sophisticated automated system trying to actively direct the encounter. It doesn't necessarily have to succeed in its goal, just do well enough for something recognizable to survive.

Comment: PcMan Yes, that was a typo, sorry.
LorenPechtel I used http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/usefultables.php#boom, and it looks like it should have been tons, not kilos. I just read the unit wrong. 
ChristopherJamesHuff You're probably right. I put those in as another possibility.
I fixed those two typos.
And yes, gravity assists could help some but at that point, the calculations would get really complicated. I chose to just assume it misses the moon (and other objects) to simplify things.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff Yeah, it's some pretty extreme luck but not completely impossible.  Entering at anything less than orbital velocity is completely impossible.

Comment: The capsule does not have to have boosters. With some heatshields, and shallow entry so that most of the speed is shed by aerobraking, enough will be left to make it possible to recognize the alien inside.

Answer (score 16):

### No.

Now, I'm no expert in this area, but it seems to me that considering how twenty-ton meteors burn up in the atmosphere on a regular basis, your alien has a 0% chance of reaching the ground before he completely sublimates. In other words: the alien itself won't survive his extreme skydive.

However, for the purposes of discussion, let's say that he's a member of the Evil Commonwealth of the Fraternal Order of Mind Your Own Darn Business. As a result, he is wearing their standard-issue handwavium armor, which, among other things, is re-entry-proof. In this case, the armor won't sublimate with the rest of the body.

Unfortunately for the people at SETI, it won't be recognizable as armor (or, for that matter, anything <strike>man</strike> alien-made) once it hits the ground. I don't care how strong this armor is, **it still can't possibly survive hitting the ground at 40,000+ km/h.** Not even the Fraternal Order is capable of that kind of magic.

As a result, I can conclusively say that there is a -10% chance that everybody will say "oh hey, that's an alien!" Sure, SETI & Co. will obviously be up in arms about how this meteor was smaller than it should have been, but they *always* say that.

[Obligatory XKCD](https://xkcd.com/2359/):

[image: This is a definite case of the top-right panel.]

Comment: To add to the XKCD comic:  Even the term UFO does not denote aliens exist.   The Flying Object is unidentified.  It could be alien in origin, or it could be terrestrial but something we can't determine (very rare atmospheric pheonomena that has not yet been documented, poor witness description of the well known by science phenomena, swamp gas changing the way a drunk hillbilly sees venus, a not-weather balloon designed for covert espionage against a hostile country that the military claims is a weather balloon to keep the secret hush hush).

Comment: I expect impact speed will be much less than 40,000 kph.  Earth has a substantial atmosphere (citation needed for physical properties) and the re-entry proof armor should hit terminal velocity and burn off excess speed during the descent.  Whether the armor can protect the occupant against being roasted alive (or roasted while hibernating) is up to the needs of the story.

Answer (score 3):

If the suit survives re-entry, there will absolutely be big enough chunks at the scene for people to piece together what happened. Meteors of human size are [slowed](https://www.amsmeteors.org/fireballs/faqf/#12) to around terminal velocity by the time they pass through most of the atmosphere, and it should be apparent that the terminal velocity of a falling body is even slower than that of a rock. While something like a person may or may not break completely upon hitting the ground at that speed, his equipment (or just his anatomy) could be very plausibly pieced together and recognized as alien.

Of course, this entails that the alien has a suit capable of surviving re-entry, which, as others have noted, occurs at tens of kilometers per second — our spacecraft use big sheets of thermal tiles to protect themselves, and those are definitely far more heavy-duty than some flame-retardant fabric. Most likely, the body gets disintegrated on re-entry and nobody finds anything larger than utterly uninteresting dust.

Comment: It's hard to imagine what would be going through a person's (or alien's) head as they donned a suit capable of surviving re-entry heating. "Maybe I'll hit something soft"?

Comment: Any suit with enough delta V can survive re-entry. You just need rocket motors powered by future alien tech to slow it down so that it enters the atmosphere at a few hundred MPH, then uses the rocket motors to land softly.

Comment: All the suit needs to survive reentry heating is a stonking huge magnetic field. This will induce a lot of drag in the reentry plasma at very high altitudes, where heating transfer is still very low. It needs a very powerful magnet, but hey, alien tech! The suit will slow down very high (~60km), then freefall at low supersonic speed, until it hits dense air, then fall like a skydiver without a parachute. Very survivable(for the suit, not to contents)

Answer (score 3):

### Mishandled capture attempt

Considering the amount of amateur astronomy chances are decent it will get spotted long before it collides with the earth. If it's obviously humaniform there would likely be attempts to capture it before it burns up in the atmosphere. If the window to do so is short, the attempts may well be kind of shoddy. On it's own it's exceedingly unlikely to survive re-entry, however perhaps Musk or Virgin or some gov't or other sends up a capture rocket ... It's not at all unlikely that something would go wrong, possibly "dropping" the body from the lower atmosphere. Consider also that if multiple entities are competing to try and be the one to acquire the "space man popsicle" they could also interfere with each other, causing an accidental "drop".

Comment: Unless our dear alien is very large or very shiny (probably both), I'm not really sure it would really be noticed by anyone. [It is currently estimated that only half of near-Earth objects larger than 140 m have been detected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-Earth_object#Projects_to_minimize_the_threat).

Answer (score 0):

> Question: Can I expect to find enough of the alien to know that it is an alien (body, clothes, or equipment)?

**Of course**

You see, the good thing with aliens is that you can do pretty much anything with them. There is little that alien technology and mysterious alien motives can not justify. From crop circles to mutilated cows to a silent metal monolith standing in the Utah desert.

Coming to your alien: he is no *schlemiel* at all. **They** burned up in the atmosphere, well their remains. He was different. He was a Basilisk rider. And, if you are asking, **this** is a basilisk!

[image]

[Basilisk war droid](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Basilisk_war_droid)

He was on the ship, on his way to the Basilisk bay. Riding it he would have plummeted from orbit on the heavily defended world below. Because that is how you fight with such a beast!

Of course given that the rider is exposed to extremely harsh conditions both during the fall from orbit and incoming fire a heavy armor is worn. He wears no common spacesuit but something which is perfectly capable of acting as a heat shield, armor from shrapnel and shield from energy weapons.

Of course he died long ago, while floating in space among the debris of his spaceship. The debris slowly getting scattered apart while he headed on a very peculiar trajectory that, of all places, ended at 6925 Hollywood Blvd, Hollywood, CA 90028

> The body is obviously frozen rock solid. 70 Kg of mass.

Well, this race of powerful warriors have the size of a red panda. Don't laugh! Red pandas can be fierce warriors too!

[image: Red Panda Fight!]

All the rest of the mass is the armor (which acts as a powered exoskeleton)

P.S. and BONUS: You want to know how it feels like to ride a Basilisk war droid from orbit?

[Canderous Ordo reminiscing his own riding on a Basilisk War droid.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D883YDu-PzU)